# Can we determine the set of all angles that can be trisected

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction

Using a straight edge and a pair of compasses only, it is imporssible to trisect angles like $\pi /3$. In fact, if we want the $x$ in $4x^3-3x-c=0,c=\cos 3\alpha$ to be constructible, we must have at least one rational root. Otherwise the degree of field extension $\mathbb Q(x)$ will be $3$, which is not a power of $2$, hence not constructible.

Question: how can we find the set of all angles that can be trisected?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See [Wikipedia on constructible angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#Constructible_angles)  You can construct any angle that is $2\pi$ divided by a Fermat prime, $2^{2^n}+1.$ We know of $3,5,17,65537$, but there may be others.  Then you can bisect and add these as much as you want.

Comment: As mentioned on Wikipedia (again), $\frac{3\pi}7$ is _trisectible_, just that neither it nor $\frac\pi7$ are constructible on their own...

Answer (score 1):

Remember that we do not require the original or trisected angle to be *constructible on their own*. For example, $\frac\pi7$ is trisectible since the difference between this angle and the constructible $\frac\pi6$ is $\frac\pi{42}$, which can be doubled to give the trisected angle $\frac\pi{21}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) gives a characterisation of all trisectible angles as those angles $\theta$ where $4x^3-3x-\cos\theta$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q(\cos\theta)$. This differs from the characterisation of all angles whose trisections are constructible by adjoining $\cos\theta$ to $\mathbb Q$.